# Add New Column To Dataframe Using Merge Within For Loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a major dataframe and 70 smaller dataframes. I would like to merge each of the 70 dataframes in the list with the main dataframe (so I end up with one huge dataframe).

The small dataframes all have 2 columns, but all have a different number of rows. I would like to do two things:

1)Change the name of the second column (by adding a character to the column 1 name)
2) Then merge that small column to the main column.

Here is what I have in mind:

```
colnames(SmallDf1)[2] <- paste(colnames(SmallDf1)[1], "_1")
main_Df <- merge(main_Df, SmallDf1, by.x = "NAME", by.y = names(SmallDf1)[1], all.x = TRUE)
```

This is obviously, just for a single data frame. Does anyone have ideas for doing this for all 70 dataframes? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do all the data frames have the same number of rows?

Comment: No they do not, their rows all differ.

Comment: Does the merge column always have the same name?

Comment: The main dataframe does (it is "NAME"), the smaller dataframes do not.

Comment: If the merge column always had the same name in the set of smaller dataframes, you could add them all to a list, and then `lapply()` it to do the merges.  With different names, it could get ugly.

Comment: what is "NAME"?, since all the small dataframes have different colnames, how can you merge using "NAME"?. Maybe my question is ambiguous..allow me illustrate. main_Df has "NAME", and smallDf1 has "NAME", so you can merge the two, but the second smalldf2,does it also contain "NAME", or does it use a different id to merge ie the colname(smalldf2)[1]??.

Comment: It uses a different ID to merge each time.